# How to remove elements from an array if they have a common part in the beginning?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say my array looks like this:

`something, something-ab, something-xy, something-xy-pq, apple, apple-banana, apple-something, potato, cat`

I can iterate over all the elements and keep checking the value of all elements after them to see if the first value is a substring but I wanted to know if there is a more clever way of converting the above array to:

`something, apple, potato, cat`

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: So, you wanna group them by the "prefix"? Or what?

Comment: How are "something" and "apple" determined? Are you asking for the two most common prefixes? Or do you want the algorithm to determine that on its own?

Comment: I am not sure what is your condition is to pick uniq item. But you can try _.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee]) http://underscorejs.org/#uniq.

Comment: @vothaison No, I just want elements that are completely unique. I have added to more elements to the sample array to illustrate what I mean. :)

Comment: Does having the word "some" in your array rule out "something" and "something-ab" and ...

Comment: @Richard No, it doesn't. The part before the first `-` should be common to  all these elements. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
new Set(array.map(word => word.split('-')[0]))
```

How does this work?

- Use `map` to create a new array
- For each word, split by `-` and choose first element
- Use a `Set` to remove duplicates

Comment: Could someone please explain what `word.split('-')[0]` means syntactically speaking? I know what `word.split('-')` does but not `word.split('-')[0]`, I've only seen the usage `array[0]` before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with ES6, try this,

```js
var array = ["something", "something-ab", "something-xy", "apple", "apple-banana", "apple-something", "potato", "cat"];


console.log([...new Set(array.map(x=> x.split('-')[1] || x.split('-')[0] ))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you can do something with [reduce](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) like this:

```
array.reduce(function(ans, v){
    if(!v.includes(ans[ans.length-1]))
        ans.push(v);
    return ans;
}, []);
```

And if the values are not sorted the way your example shows you can [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) it before.